# ggplot2 vertical profile plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a vertical profile wit the standard deviation shaded. I use my usual command line that i use for timeseries plots but it works wrong for the vertical profile.

```
ggplot(data = df_join2, aes(x = mean, y = plm, color = variable)) + 
      geom_line(aes(x = mean, color = variable), size = 2) + 
      scale_colour_manual(name = varnm, values = clr2) +
      geom_ribbon(aes(x = mean, xmin = mean - sd, xmax = mean + sd, fill = variable), alpha = .3, show.legend = FALSE) +
      scale_fill_manual(name = varnm, values = clr2) +
      scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse", breaks = c(1000,750,500,250,100)) +
      xlab(nm2) + ylab("Pressure (mb)") + theme_bw() +  theme(legend.key = element_blank()) + 
      guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c(1), shape = c(NA)))) + #theme(plot.margin=unit(c(1,3,1,1),"cm"))+
      theme(legend.position = "none")
```

The data i use is:

```
    plm     variable    mean     sd
1   99.0    hum 1.441467e-08    2.255813e-08
2   118.0   hum 1.274516e-08    2.816413e-08
3   139.0   hum 1.871454e-08    4.622236e-08
4   161.5   hum 2.545867e-08    8.023293e-08
5   185.0   hum 1.390923e-08    1.114903e-07
6   210.0   hum 1.152322e-07    1.153853e-07
7   237.0   hum 2.782828e-07    1.350924e-07
8   266.5   hum 4.848867e-07    1.995094e-07
9   299.0   hum 8.357763e-07    3.158922e-07
10  335.0   hum 1.397717e-06    5.110624e-07
11  375.0   hum 2.135646e-06    8.599465e-07
12  418.5   hum 3.393004e-06    1.359676e-06
13  465.0   hum 5.635352e-06    2.032474e-06
14  514.0   hum 7.140172e-06    2.816654e-06
15  565.0   hum 1.009809e-05    3.730973e-06
16  616.5   hum 1.309488e-05    4.803978e-06
17  667.0   hum 1.679745e-05    5.979570e-06
18  716.0   hum 1.859773e-05    7.257538e-06
19  762.5   hum 2.126635e-05    8.653999e-06
20  805.0   hum 2.098323e-05    9.801954e-06
21  842.5   hum 2.433523e-05    1.100483e-05
22  875.0   hum 2.289352e-05    1.181187e-05
23  903.5   hum 2.477932e-05    1.241182e-05
24  929.5   hum 2.357829e-05    1.299938e-05
25  953.0   hum 2.027214e-05    1.278464e-05
26  974.0   hum 1.948147e-05    1.705238e-05
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Can you add how `clr2` is defined?

Comment: looks quite nice when I try it.. whats wrong with it?

Comment: @Edo clr2 is just the color.. you can run it without that

Comment: yeah I know, I wanted to help him make a fully reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way. Add `orientation = "y"` in `geom_line`.
(I've commented where `clr2` and `nm2` were present because I don't know them)

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df_join2, aes(x = mean, y = plm, color = variable)) + 
 geom_line(aes(color = variable), size = 2, orientation = "y") + 
 # scale_colour_manual(name = varnm, values = clr2) +
 geom_ribbon(aes(x = mean, xmin = mean - sd, xmax = mean + sd, fill = variable), alpha = .3, show.legend = FALSE) +
 # scale_fill_manual(name = varnm, values = clr2) +
 scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse", breaks = c(1000,750,500,250,100)) +
 # xlab(nm2) +
 ylab("Pressure (mb)") + 
 theme_bw() +  
 theme(legend.key = element_blank()) + 
 guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c(1), shape = c(NA)))) + #theme(plot.margin=unit(c(1,3,1,1),"cm"))+
 theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]